# array enviado por ajax no llega completo a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo un array de 61 elementos, cada elemento de ese array es otro array

```
Array(61) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ],
```

El asunto es que cuando lo envió como parámetro a php y le hago un `print_r` solo me imprime 48 elementos

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'controllers/sendMailAcuse.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    //receivers: receivers,
    action: 'sendAccuse',
    response: 'json',
    package: source // este es mi array
  }
}).always(function(res) {
  dom.$accuseDialog.modal('hide');
  showMessage(res.message);
});
```

¿Alguien sabe porque??

Comment: como generas "source" o que estructura tiene tu arreglo?

Comment: Coloca tu estructura del arreglo.

Comment: Tambien puedes probar a darle formato JSON para obligar a que sea una cadena con JSON.stringify(Arreglo); en JS y $arreglo=json_decode($_POST["arreglo"],true); en PHP :)

Comment: gracias amigo ruben, si me fue de gran utilidad JSON.stringify(Arreglo), solo una pregunta mas, que es lo que hace JSON.stringify(), o porque no me llegaban los 61 registros del array?

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene el uso de `package` ? Siempre he visto que se usa `data` para indicar los datos que quieren enviarse. Estuve revisando la documentación y no encuentro nada que hable de `package` como parámetro de una petición Ajax.